# Setting up a Word 2007 installation that was originally an Arabic Locale for American English Locale?

Tags: microsoft-word, locale

A laptop I have has Microsoft Word 2007 installed for the Arabic Locale.  I'm trying to get it working with the American English Locale.  While I've managed to get it to type English characters, it's still stuck typing from right-to-left, and when I press the left arrow key, it moves the cursor right, when I press the right arrow key it moves the cursor left.

I thought the problem might have had something to do with `Normal.dotm` being different, so I replaced it with a copy of one from work, but the problem still occurs.

I've changed the locale on the laptop itself, it used to be set to Egypt, but now it is set to United States.

I also thought that making a new word document in a folder or on the desktop (as opposed to inside the program) would fix the issue as it does in Excel, but it did not.

Comment: Have you installed the `American English` language pack?

Comment: I don't know I'll have to check...

Comment: Okay the language packs are all installed, it just needed to have the `Primary Language` set to `English (American)` and additionally it required a restart.

Comment: If you resolved your own problem post the solution as an answer.